# how to include external libraries to arduino extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

> pnp_device.h:10:42: fatal error: digitaltwin_device_client_ll.h: No
>   such file or directory

I'm using arduino and azure iot tools to use azure iot plug and play feature.
I generated the plug and play code stub using vscode azure iot tools, but while uploading the code the above error is raised.
As the file missing is in the external library (Azure-iot-sdk-c) I tried adding its path in c_cpp_properties.json even though the error persists.
I want to know why it is happening ?
I need some help...

Comment: What is the arduino sdk you are using? Did you completed successfully [one of the quickstarts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/quickstart-create-pnp-device-linux) from the documentation before trying with arduino? Also understand that [Azure IoT Device Workbench does not support generic Arduino devices.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-iot-workbench#arduino)

Comment: I have completed quickstart of iot central which is done by just drag and dropping a .bin file to mxchip. I have written a device capability model and created a code stub using pnp code generation now I'm trying to upload that code to mxchip using arduino extension this error "pnp_device.h:10:42: fatal error: digitaltwin_device_client_ll.h: No such file or directory" is coming, I also tried using to upload it using workbench facing same error

Answer (score 1):

We have a devkit SDK especially for the PNP. You can follow this [readme](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mxchip-iot-devkit-pnp) and change the version of SDK.